# Error final variable and non-constant identifiers using lowerCamelCase

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have an error when making json on flutter

can someone please fix it

here the code i wrote

```
class LoginResponseModel {
  final String status;
  final String message;
  final String kid;
  final String uid;
  final String email;
  final String password;

    LoginRequestModel({this.status, this.message, this.kid, 
       this.uid, this.email, this.password});


    factory LoginResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> 
       json) {
    return LoginResponseModel(status: json["status"] != null ? 
       json["status"]: "", error:json["error"] != null ? 
       json["error"] : "", );
    }
   }

   class LoginRequestModel {
         String email;
         String password;

    LoginRequestModel({this.email, this.password});

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
    'email': email.trim(),
    'password': password.trim(),
     };
    return map;
    }
   }
```

> Error on class LoginResponseModel says Non-nullable instance field
> 'status' must be initialized
>
> Error On LoginRequestModel ({this.status" says LoginRequestModel must have a method body because isn't abstract
>
> Error on LoginRequestModel({this.email" says The parameter 'email' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type. but the implicit default is 'null'.

i really appreciate the answer

Comment: Please provide the full error message.

Comment: already added the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Named arguments in Dart are optional if the `required` keyword is not being used. If a named argument is not set, it will instead be set to a default value. The default value will here be `null` unless other default value is specified.

Since you are running with null-safety enabled, that means your code is invalid since e.g. `final String status;` this is now being set to `null` by default which is not allowed since the type `String` does not allow `null`. If `null` should be allowed, you need to use the type `String?` instead.

Another solution is to set all named arguments so they are required to be set when calling the constructor. This can be done like this. Also, you now need to set all arguments when calling the `LoginResponseModel` constructor. I have just assumed you want the empty String for all fields in case of `null`:

```
class LoginResponseModel {
  final String status;
  final String message;
  final String kid;
  final String uid;
  final String email;
  final String password;

  LoginResponseModel({
    required this.status,
    required this.message,
    required this.kid,
    required this.uid,
    required this.email,
    required this.password,
  });

  factory LoginResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      LoginResponseModel(
        status: json["status"] as String? ?? "",
        message: json["message"] as String? ?? "",
        kid: json["kid"] as String? ?? "",
        uid: json["uid"] as String? ?? "",
        email: json["email"] as String? ?? "",
        password: json["password"] as String? ?? "",
      );
}

class LoginRequestModel {
  String email;
  String password;

  LoginRequestModel({
    required this.email,
    required this.password,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => <String, dynamic>{
        'email': email.trim(),
        'password': password.trim(),
      };
}
```

For more details about Dart null-safety, please read: https://dart.dev/null-safety. For this specific issue about optional named arguments you can read: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#required-named-parameters

Comment: what if i change the status to the boolean is that will get the error message again

Comment: @ImamRizkyGANTENG `boolean` does also have the value `null` by default in Dart unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: ah okay okay, btw still didn't change anything its still give me the error

Comment: @ImamRizkyGANTENG Yes, because your factory constructor `LoginResponseModel.fromJson` does not set all the parameters expected from the `LoginResponseModel` constructor. Again, if some of the parameters needs to be optional you need to provide default values or allow `null` by using nullable types.

Comment: @ImamRizkyGANTENG Updated my answer so it now contains all your code. The `??` operator allows us to use another value if the left-side is ended up being `null`.